# Get all the names of the .txt files inside a directory

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm having a problem getting just the names of the .txt files inside a directory.
I want to get all the names of all the .txt files inside my application's main directory and add them to a listbox. The code I'm using is working but it's returning the full directory while I only want the name of files. Here's the code:

```
 String^ folder = Application::StartupPath ;
 array<String^>^ file = Directory::GetFiles(folder, "*.txt");

 for (int i=0; i<file->Length; i++) 
 {
    listBox1->Items->Add(file[i] );
 }
```

This is returning the full directory, for example: C:\programs\asd.txt
And I only want: asd.txt

How can I get just the name of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Path.GetFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
for (int i=0; i<file->Length; i++) 
{
    listBox1->Items->Add(Path::GetFileName(file[i]) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `basename()` function.

e.g.

```
file = basename(Directory::GetFiles(folder, "*.txt");
```